# Ajax functionality with my own library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I am writing my own small library as jQuery just doesn't cut it for me, and honestly I'd rather not, as I'd rather know exactly what is going on in my code! Anyways I am trying to write an ajax function that would be written like so `_$.ajax()` but the problem is I'm not getting the functionality that I need as its saying that the CORS is not valid, yet I know it should be as when I use `$.get || $.post` it works fine...

Function:

```
 var ajax = {
     url: null,
     type: "GET",
     cache: null,
     data: null,
     content: null,
     state: 0,
     xhr: null,
     timeout:0,
     responseType: "",
     done:function(data){
     //not sure on here
     },
    init: function () {
      var ids = ['MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP'];
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            try {
                ajax.xhr = new ActiveXObject(ids[i]);
                break;
            } catch (e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.xhr.open(ajax.type, ajax.url, true);
    ajax.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", ajax.content !== null ? ajax.content : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    if(ajax.cache !== null){
    ajax.xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT");
    }
    ajax.process();
},
process: function () {
    ajax.xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.xhr.readyState == 4) {
           if(ajax.xhr.status == 200){
           if(typeof ajax.done != 'undefined'){
              ajax.done(ajax.xhr.responseText);
                      //old way was ajax.completion = ajax.xhr.responseText 
                      //then in the ajax.ajax it would return(ajax.completion);
             }else{
             return false;
             }
           }
        }
    };
    if (ajax.type.toUpperCase() === 'GET') {
        ajax.xhr.send();
        ajax.state = 1;
    } else if (ajax.type.toUpperCase() === 'POST') {
        ajax.xhr.send(data);
        ajax.state = 1;
        }
        return (ajax.response);
},
ajax: function (opts) {
     ajax.url = opts.url,
     ajax.type = opts.type !== undefined ? opts.type : ajax.type,
     ajax.cache = opts.cache,
     ajax.content = opts.content,
     ajax.data = opts.data;
     ajax.responseType = opts.responseType ? opts.responseType : ajax.responseType;
     ajax.timeout = opts.timeout ? opts.timeout : ajax.timeout;
     opts.done(ajax.done);
     ajax.init(); 
       }
    };
```

**EDIT**
I've updated my code, as to user3165879 answer to provide a functionality. I am getting the xhr.response text, though for some reason whenever I try to ``` alert``console ```or`return` it it just says undefined.

I want to be able to write my code as so:

```
 var content;
 _$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"whatever.url.com",
    done:function(data){
    content+= data;  
  }
});
```

As you can see I don't have a real `done` inside my code as I'm not positive where to start, never really fully understood the process of ajax. Couldn't find any clear cut documentation to this.

Comment: What do you mean with CORS error? The exact error message would always be more helpful. Was it something like `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.tld' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: Yes I am sorry for not specifying that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the done option on readystate = 4 and status = 200

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(xhr.readyState== 4){
   if(xhr.status==200){
     if(typeof opts.done != 'undefined'){
         opts.done(xhr.responseText);
     }
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
```

};

Hope it helps

Comment: As you can see I've updated my question with a more up to date code as I changed a lot of it. I now have three different functions `ajax.ajax` which is what we will use as `_$.ajax` and `ajax.init` as well as `ajax.process`  I added the code you have just not return anything as not sure exactly how to proceed any further.